# Sum elements of two int lists

Tags: haskell

I created the new type

```
type Digits = [String]
type BigNumber = Digits
```

and I was trying to create a function that sums two BigNumbers by turning the string list into a INT list with:

```
somaBN :: BigNumber -> BigNumber -> BigNumber
somaBN a b = zipWith + (map (read a)) (map (read b))
```

But I get the error

```
Couldn't match type ‘(a0 -> b0 -> c0) -> [a0] -> [b0] -> [c0]’
                 with ‘[String]’
  Expected type: BigNumber
    Actual type: (a0 -> b0 -> c0) -> [a0] -> [b0] -> [c0]

• Probable cause: ‘(+)’ is applied to too few arguments
  In the expression: zipWith + (map (read a)) (map (read b))
  In an equation for ‘somaBN’:
      somaBN a b = zipWith + (map (read a)) (map (read b))typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)


• Couldn't match expected type ‘(a0 -> b0 -> c0)
                                -> [a0] -> [b0] -> [c0]’
              with actual type ‘[b1]’
• Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely
    ‘(map (read a)) (map (read b))’
  In the expression: zipWith + (map (read a)) (map (read b))
  In an equation for ‘somaBN’:
      somaBN a b = zipWith + (map (read a)) (map (read b))typecheck(-Wdeferred-type-errors)
```

Comment: Since `Digits = [String]`, you need to convert the elementwise sum back to a list of `String`s.

Comment: what about `(+)` ? Because that's an infix operator, you have to wrap it in braces in order to pass it to other functions, I think.

Comment: `zipWith + (map (read a)) (map (read b))` parses as `( zipWith ) + ( ... )`, which is not what you want. Try `zipWith (+) (map ...) (map ...)`. This won't solve all the issues, but it's a first step.

Answer (score 1):

Since functions can be passed to other functions, and some functions are traditionally written infix, Haskell needs a way to distinguish the program "add `x` and `y`" from the program "call `x` with the addition function and `y` as parameters". Without special syntax, one way to differentiate would be to always use infix functions as infix, and require the programmer to expand them into a lambda if they wanted to pass it as an argument:

```
x + y -- add x and y
x (\a b -> a + b) y -- pass + as an argument to x
```

It's a common enough need, and that solution is clunky enough, that there's special syntax. Wrapping an operator in parentheses eliminates its infix-ness:

```
x (+) y -- pass + as an argument to x
```